# How to save position of min_element result?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

How can I save the value of min_element?  It says it's a forward iterator but I can't seem to figure out how to save (assign to a variable to) it.  I want to be able to access it by location in the vector.  All I can find is examples of using the actual element (using *min_element() ).  I tried

`iterator< forward_iterator_tag, vector<string> > min_word_iterator = min_element(first_words_in_subvecs.begin(), first_words_in_subvecs.end());`

but that didn't work.  I'm going to replace the element at that index with a different element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [distance](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/distance/) provided by stl to find the position.
You need to pass the iterator returned by min_element to it to get the position

See this example code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  vector<int> myvec;
  int i = 0;
  for (i=8; i>0; i--)
  {
      myvec.push_back (i*10);
  }

  for (i=0; i<8; i++)
  {
      cout<<"At pos :"<<i<<"|val is:"<<myvec.at(i)<<endl;
  }

  int min_pos = distance(myvec.begin(),min_element(myvec.begin(),myvec.end()));
  cout << "The distance is: " << min_pos << "|value is "<<*min_element(myvec.begin(),myvec.end())<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: how do i just get the int index of it?

Comment: Refer to the example in the answer which i have posted with my answer

Comment: Also `min_element(myvec.begin(), myvec.end()) - myvec.begin()` should be OK, does anyone know if it is different from `distance(myvec.begin(),min_element(myvec.begin(),myvec.end()))` ?

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
std::vector<T>::iterator minIt = std::min_element(v.begin(),v.end());
//where T is the type of elements in vector v.

T minElement = *minIt; //or T & minElement = *minIt; to avoid copy!
```

And in C++11 (if your compiler supports `auto` keyword), then this:

```
auto minIt = std::min_element(v.begin(), v.end());
//type of minIt will be inferred by the compiler itself

T minElement = *minIt; //or auto minElement = *minIt;
                       //or auto & minElement = *minIt; to avoid copy
```

Comment: Or in C++11, `auto minIt = ...`.

Comment: I fail to understand why there's a need to say "and in C++11 ...", or even why start off with the C++03 way. C++03 is past, Latin is dead, there are only 8 planets in our system, let's move on shall we?

Comment: @wilhelmtell:  C++03 is past only in theory (in language specification), many compilers still do not support many features of C++11. That is why I provided a C++03 solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

When you have two random access iterators, you can generally subtract one from the other to find the distance between them.  Thus, once you've got the iterator `it`, you can find the index of the element it refers to with `it - my_vector.begin()`.